# Getting a Forbidden when trying to access my controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've created a form that when submitted it needs to go to a controller function.

At the moment when I'm submitting my form I keep getting

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /client_area/shop/payment-gateway on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I've done forms before but this is the first time this has happened to me and it has me stumped.

my form

```
<div class="payment-form">
    <form action="{{ route('payment.gateway') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        
        <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{{ route('payment.success') }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="{{ route('payment.cancel') }}"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="m_payment_id" value="{{ $invoice_number }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" class="completePrice" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Item">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_description" value="A test product">

        <input type="hidden" name="delivery_collection" class="delivery_collection" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="delivery_fee" class="delivery_fee" value="{{ $delivery }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="delivery_address" class="delivery_address" value="{{ $address }}">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right confirm-order">
            Confirm Order
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

my routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function(){
    Route::get('/account/dashboard', 'UsersController@accountDashboard')->name('account.dashboard');
    Route::get('/account/details', 'UsersController@personalDetails')->name('account.details');
    Route::get('/account/track-orders', 'UsersController@trackOrders')->name('account.track-orders');
    Route::get('/account/invoices', 'UsersController@invoices')->name('account.invoices');
    Route::get('/account/address', 'UsersController@addressesIndex')->name('account.addresses.index');
    Route::get('/account/sort-orders', 'UsersController@sortOrders')->name('account.sort-orders');
    Route::get('/account/order-details/{invoice_number}', 'UsersController@orderDetails')->name('account.order-details');
    Route::get('/account/invoice-pdf/{id}', 'UsersController@invoicesPdf')->name('account.invoices.pdf');
    Route::get('/account/create-address', 'UsersController@createAddress')->name('account.create.address');
    Route::get('/account/edit-address/{id}', 'UsersController@editAddress')->name('account.edit.address');
    Route::get('/delivery-confirmation', 'PublicController@deliveryConfirmation')->name('cart.deliveryConfirmation');
    Route::get('/account/edit-delivery-address/{id}', 'UsersController@editDeliveryAddress')->name('account.edit.delivery.address');
    Route::get('/payment-success', 'PublicController@successPayment')->name('payment.success');
    Route::get('/payment-cancel', 'PublicController@cancelPayment')->name('payment.cancel');

    Route::post('/account/personal-details', 'UsersController@postPersonalDetails')->name('post.personal-details');
    Route::post('/account/business-details', 'UsersController@postBusinessDetails')->name('post.business-details');
    Route::post('/account/addresses-radio/{id}', 'UsersController@postAddressesRadio')->name('account.post.addresses.radio');
    Route::post('/account/create-address', 'UsersController@postAddress')->name('account.post.address');
    Route::post('/account/edit-address/{id}', 'UsersController@updateAddress')->name('account.update.address');
    Route::post('/payment-gateway', 'PublicController@paymentGateway')->name('payment.gateway');

    Route::delete('/account/delete-delivery-address/{id}', 'UsersController@deleteDeliveryAddress')->name('account.delete.delivery.address');
});
```

I've only done a `dd()` to make sure I hit the right function

```
public function paymentGateway()
{
    dd('this is a payment gateway');
}
```

My Auth Middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I see when I go through the network tab. Because it's alot of images I thought it would be better to have it as a link then just pasting the images here.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir2UO.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28nLU.jpg)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40v2D.jpg)

[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/620BG.jpg)

[Image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz7TW.jpg)

[Image 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDWdn.jpg)

[Image 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlKve.jpg)

[Image 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL8Dc.jpg)

Comment: Is your project configured properly? Do the other forms in this project work as expected?

Comment: yep all my other forms work fine. That's why I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel comes with Cross Site Request Forgery protection. You need to also pass a field named csrf-token as stated here in the documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

If you do not want this protection you must include the route in the VerifyCsrfToken Middleware to exclude the checking.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Try this to see if that solves your issue.

Comment: I added `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` to my site and it still didn't work

Comment: Try excluding the csrf check to see if this is the issue https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris. Do you still get the same issue.

Comment: Also please include your web and auth middlewares in stackoverflow so I can take a look on how they are configured.

Comment: I haven't touched my auth or web middleware, I've added my auth middleware to my question buy i'm not really sure where to find the web one

Comment: Can you take a look of when you make the post does the csrf-token get passed to the route? Use the network tab in your browser.

Comment: Yes, but can you see the request?

Comment: Do you have XDEBUG installed?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the images of my network tab. I've installed XDEBUG. I'm still looking at how you use it

Comment: You use it with your IDE like PHPStorm. You can put breakpoints in your IDE and stop php to see the whole environment at that point. Here is more information https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-code.html.